# Every time my computer restarts, VSCode's spacing rules break

Tags: visual-studio-code

This has happened to me the last 3 or 4 times I've restarted my computer. I'm not entirely sure how to fix it, I've tried restarting VSCode but that hasn't helped. Sometimes it fixes itself but I'm not sure how to recreate the fix either.

When I save a React/`.js` file, this weird auto-formatting rule kicks in which makes my code a complete nightmare:

`<
        div className = "example" >`

I'm running VSCode 1.33.1 on OS X 10.14.4.

Has anyone else experienced this?